# How to do Simulink model run in Raspberry Pi after power on (booting) as standalone?

Tags: raspberry-pi, simulink

I build a Simulink model to control Dc motor, load into the board, stop Simulink model and plug out the power and Ethernet cable.

Does the Simulink model that has been loaded in the Raspberry Pi board work alone after Raspberry Pi power on (booting / startup) without running Simulink model again on the computer via Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [official support package](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-simulink.html).

You will find a binary application built for your system in your home directory. The name of the folder is identical to the name of your simulink model.

You can use ssh to connect to your raspberry and start the application manually each time you boot the system. If you wish to start it automatically, [check this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/raspberry-pi-starting-programs-automatically-on-startup).

Make sure to stop the application before you use the support package to load a new application, for example when you update your model and built it again.

Comment: The Simulink model is converted to an executable that runs on the Raspberry Pi board. Typically, the executable is saved in "/home/pi/<Simulink model name_rtt>/MW/Simulink model name directory. The name of the executable is the same as the Simulink model name.

Comment: I connected a USB camera with Raspberry Pi to control Dc motor,I can't run the executable file from VNC viewer, and the usb camera doesn't work      from guvcview from VNC viewer also.The model run normally from computer in (normal and external) modes

Comment: I recommend to ask a new question and describe in detail what you did. What is not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: And do you have a reason to use vnc? The deployed applications don't have any user interface.

Comment: 1- when I go to Raspberry Pi via vnc to execute the file (execute in terminal) the terminal window appeared and no image is saved in the directory and no motion for the Dc motor.2-when i use guvcview from menu, the USB camera doesn't operate, Why? >>Thanks for your replay.

Comment: @AhmedDesoky: my recommendation is to first address your general issue with the camera. At https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ you will find many experts for raspberry pi. Once you got your camera working, test it with simulink again. If it does not work, please ask a new question here describing your application and all the steps you do.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, It is the first time to ask in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest supportpackage for Raspberry Pi - 18a
They introduced "Run on Boot" feature at the Simulink config set.
You can directly add a model to startup during deployment.
Refer the [supportpackage page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40313-simulink-support-package-for-raspberry-pi-hardware) for more information.